# Storing Database Security Credentials in PHP Securely

Tags: php, security, directory

Is storing database credentials one relative-level up in a directory structure (`../dbconn_inc.php`) secure?

We have a basic shared hosting account through GoDaddy that runs cPanel, with the main page being stored in `/public_html`. We are hoping to find a simple solution to securely store database credentials in a PHP include file. We have not changed any folder permissions (yet - we are willing to do so). Our primary methods of directory manipulation are cPanel's directory manager and FileZilla. At the moment, we are referencing an include file stored in the root directory (`/`), but are unsure if this is safe.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It's reasonably safe to keep your database information inside of the script, however the security of your scripts are mainly dependent on the host and how you configure and work with your server.

The only disadvantage to keeping your connection information inside of a .php file that is hosted inside of your web root would be if the server stops parsing php and outputs the script as plain text to any user loading the page, Thus it would be best to keep your database config outside of the web root to keep access restricted.

Your directory would look something like this:

```
|-config
|   --database.php
|
|-public_html (Root for www.mysite.com)
|   --init.php
```

Then in init.php you could use something like `require "../config/database.php"` to get the information you needed.

**Extra info**

[This question has been asked before and has some good answers](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13353/password-in-file-php)

[Alternative methods to including from outside the web root](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/php-include-path.html)

Comment: I would also argue that pretty much everything with the exception of assets  (css, js, images) and your main `index.php` or whatever file you use as the entry point should be kept outside the webroot.